# i recently converted an excel workbook to a csv file , (utf-8) . however it was not being loaded

Tags: pandas, parsing, data-science

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6cD7.png)

I even tried going through the different encoding , I was just overwhelmed by the amount of information.

Comment: Try using \\ in place of \ ?

Comment: nope , it aint working . to be honest i dont even know what the problem is

Comment: The column in each line of your csv is not same.

Comment: It's hard to give you good advice without seeing the file you're trying to read. In general, you can help people help you by presenting as much information as possible, and by avoiding the use of images which are hard for read for some of us whose eyes are not as functional as yours. But my guess is that the first three lines of your file are not useful data. They are titles or something like that, and Pandas insists that all rows of a CSV have the some number of fields. `read_csv` has a million options; one of them is the number of lines at the beginning of the file to ignore.